# How to store each line in a txt file to a new list in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

How can I create a new list for each line in a txt file in netlogo? For example, I have a file containing these values:

```
[89 64 90 1 97 45 109]
[89 64 90 1 97 38 109]
[89 101 11 51 80 9 109]
[89 101 11 51 80 16 13 109]
[89 101 11 51 80 16 13 68 109]
```

And I would like to create a list for each one of these lines. i.e.

```
List1: [89 101 11 51 80 16 109]
List2: [89 101 11 51 80 9 109]
etc...
```

The number of lines in the file varies so the number of lists cannot be statically allocated.
This is the current code to loop through the file and output each line as a list in the console:

```
to DetermineRoute

  ask sensors with [color = green][
  file-open "BaseStationRoutes.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let Route file-read-line
    set Route read-from-string Route
    print Route
    print length Route ;length is the hop count
    ]
    file-close 
  ]

end
```

The end goal is to get the average length of each list to calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: you have the file reading inside an `ask sensors` block - do you really want each sensor to read the whole file and create multiple identical lists? But I am also unclear what you are trying to achieve - you want to create multiple lists, but are the lists global variables, turtle variables?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Only one sensor is green . The lists are unique to the sensor and therefore, should not be global. I am trying to calculate the average length of route and the deviation. From this outlier routes will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lacking the clarification JenB asks for, lets simply address how to store a variable number of lists of variable length.  The best structure for doing that in NetLogo is a list of lists, as lists can be of varying length and contain dissimilar elements. Your procedure above would then be

```
to DetermineRoute
  ask sensors with [color = green][
  let Routes []
  file-open "BaseStationRoutes.txt"
    while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let  Route file-read-line
    set Route read-from-string Route
    set Routes lput Route Routes
;    print length Route ;length is the hop count
    ]
    file-close 
  ]
end
```

`Routes` is initialized as an empty list, and each line of the file is appended to that list with `lput`.  Each `Route` is an item in `Routes`, e.g., the first `Route` is `item 0 Routes`, etc.  The number of Route lists is `length Routes`, and the length of (say) the third Route is `length item 2 Routes`.